# which values of k satisfies special property to formulate L function

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, products

Consider $x*\prod_{a=1}^{n}(1-x^a)^k$
Famously for k=24 this product satisfies the condition to be an L-Function. More information can be found [here](https://youtu.be/VTveQ1ndH1c?t=7m56s)

My question is for what other values of k, such property holds? and why?

Comment: the [Ramajuan tau function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_tau_function) given by expanding $q \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^n)^{24} = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \tau(m) q^m$ is not a L-function, but is multiplicative : $\tau(mn) = \tau(m)\tau(n)$ whenever $gcd(m,n)=1$. and the associated L-function is $F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau(n) n^{-s} = \prod_{p \in \mathcal{P}} (1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \tau(p^k)p^{-sk})$. where the last is an [Euler product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Petersson_conjecture

Comment: So for what other value of k it will be multiplicative again?

Comment: I Don't even know how to prove that $\tau$ is multiplicative, so.. and suppose $F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n f(n) $ with $f(n)$ being multiplicative, and  $x F(x)^k = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n g_k(n)$. will $g_k(n)$ being multiplicative for some $k \ne 1$ ?